# Android - json parsing

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON as shown below:

```
{
        "places": [{
            "name": "Ankola",
            "slug": "ankola",
            "category": "beach",
            "distance": "521",
            "travel_time": "8 hrs, 2 mins",
            "days": "3",
            "latitude": "14.669456",
            "longitude": "74.300952",
            "weather": "Summer 21\u00b0-36\u00b0C, Winter 12\u00b0-35\u00b0C",
            "todo": "Baskal gudda, Nadibag, Shedikuli, Keni, Belekeri",
            "about": "Ankola is a small town surrounded by numerous temples. It is in line with Arabian sea. Ankola is famous for its native breed of mango called ishaad and for cashews harvesting.",
           "image": [
                     "Cm5NXlq.jpg",
                     "9OrlQ9C.jpg",
                     "DRWZakh.jpg",
                     "dFKVgXA.jpg",
                     "5WO2nDf.jpg"
                     ]

        }]
}
```

I know how to fetch key - value pairs, but i dont know how to parse array inside json to form a string array(image - in my case)

To summarize i want something like this:
I have 5 image names under "image" tag, i want them in a string array. How can i do this?

Comment: JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObjet.getJSONArray("image");

Comment: Hope the wrong comma is a copy paste error. Also, why are the image names themselves in braces? Can you talk to whoever creates this JSON?

Comment: @rajeshwaran No it's not ;)

Comment: It is not json vaild , then how parsing image jsonarray. First correct the json format.

Comment: Okay now the OP updated the JSON and now it makes more sense, except it reads _"image": "image":_ but if you fix that, it will be fine.

Comment: I have made all the suggested changes. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
JSONArray images = yourJSONObject.getJSONArray("image");
for(int i = 0; i < images.length(); i++){
   String image = images.getString(i);
}
```

This should do the trick as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
JSONArray ja = whatEverYourJsonObject.getJSONArray("image");

for(int i=0; i<ja.length(); j++){
    String name = ja.getString(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first have to convert the JSON string to a Java object (`JSONObject`). Then, you obtain your `JSONArray` and iterate over it.

Example:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = null;
try {
    jsonObj = new JSONObject (jsonString);
    JSONArray images = itemObj.getJSONArray ("images");
    int length = images.length ();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        Log.d ("Image Filename", images.getString (i));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT: Now I see that your JSON is invalid - you have an object for each image and that object contains only the value part of the data. An example of a valid images array would be as follows:

```
{
    "image": [
        "Cm5NXlq.jpg",
        "9OrlQ9C.jpg",
        "DRWZakh.jpg",
        "dFKVgXA.jpg",
        "5WO2nDf.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

1. Create your own class which describes your data structure defined
   by those json object. As a last resort you can even generate Java
   class based on JSON string - look at 
   [jsongen](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/)
2. When you will have your own Java class (let's say `MyClass`) you can easily parse JSON to your generated Java class using [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/Home), like:

   `MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);`